# Python long to formatted string

Tags: python

I am using python to convert a long to little endian:

```
import struct

test = "0xbfffef40";
print(struct.pack('<L', long(test, 16)))
```

which displays as

```
@???
```

But I am having issues working out a nice way to print it in the form:

```
\x40\xef\xff\xbf
```

As a string to the terminal (just for logging).

Comment: Can't you do ```str('\x40\xef\xff\xbf')```?

Comment: Updated the question with more detail

Comment: I ran your code and got errors (SyntaxError on `string test` and NameError on `long`). Want to help us a bit when asking to help you?

Comment: sorry, its python so didn't need 'string'. test is input as an argument, and hence is a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code with little improvements

```
import struct
test = "0xbfffef40"
print(struct.pack('<L',int(test, base=16)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still prints as @???. I am not sure what I need to convert so that it prints the hex values as a readable string.

Comment: Which version of python are you using and in which OS ?